# How to create two groups on squid proxsy server and use dansguardian as a website filter

Tags: squid

I have two groups of staff in our organization I would like one group to access internet from 6:00-22:00 and will be accessing all websites except certain ban sites and the other group will access the internet only from 11:45-13:00 and will ban as well from certain websites. I'm confuse on how to create two separate website ban list on dansguardian and also acl statement to do this task. However below is the acl statement i wrote for the two groups but it does not produce the result i'm after, i'm new to squid and dansguardian can someone help me out on this. My end goal is to have this two groups running through the proxsy server as per the time specified to access the internet and dansguardian will filter their separate list of ban websites accordingly.

## acl

acl staff_access scr 192.168.1.0/24
acl manager_access scr 192.168.1.0/24
acl staffaccess_hrs time time S M T W H F A 11:45-13:00 16:00-22:00
acl manageraccess_hrs time S M T W H F A 6:00-22:00

## http_access

http_access allow staff_access manager_acess staffaccess_hrs manageraccess_hrs

## Squid port

http_port 3128

Comment: Edit your question to include code you've tried so far, and format your post so it's not a big wall of text. Thanks

Comment: Hi Aaaron I've edit my post again have a look and advise

Answer (score 0):

Below would be better approach.

http_access allow staffaccess_hrs staff_access
http_access allow manageraccess_hrs manager_access
http_access deny staff_access
http_access deny manager_access

Regards

Kias

Comment: Hi Kias. Thank you for your answer though it works for the managers access time it does not work out for the staff access time. Thought the staffs are restricted to access the internet to certain specific time they still access the internet as per the managers access time

Comment: The src network  is the same for the manager and staff. Could you the split the subnet or create another subnet? Better to identify the source IPs for both the groups.

Comment: Hi Kias, as you mention i did create two different IP group list for the two groups. Acl staff_access src "/etc/squid3/staff_ip.txt" Acl manager_access src "/etc/squid3/manager_ip.txt" Acl staffaccess_hrs S M T W H F A 11:30-13:00 15:30-22:00 Acl manageraccess_hrs S M T W H F A 7:00-23:00. http_access allow staffaccess_hrs staff_access http_access allow manageraccess_hrs manager_access http_access deny staff_access http_access deny manager_access. The approach above i did but still staff access the internet the same time as the managers.

Comment: Sounds good. Please share the IP group, will check & advise accordingly.